# Fractional part of Median always .5 or .0

Tags: median, fractional-part

If we find the mid value of two **integer** number,it's decimal part would always contain **.5** or **.0**  **exactly**

For Example:

(5+10)/2=7 **.5**

(6+2)/2=4 **.0**

But,in some coding challenge they asked to calculate `median` for a list of **integers**

Then they said

> please consider the closest whole number higher value in case the
>   decimal is greater than or equal to 0.5 and above and the closest
>   whole number lower value if decimal is less than 0.5

Here's the complete question!

[image]

Now I can't understand this particular quote?Can you help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Apparently, they mentioned this common *general* rounding rule in order not to give away the fact that the median cannot have other fractional parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, the phrasing is awkward. They could have sufficed to say that $\frac12$ is to be rounded up.

---

**Addendum:** In response to OPs question in the comments, presume that our sample is $\{1,5\}$. Thus the first term is $1$, the second is $5$.

According to the formula above, the median is:

$$\frac{(\text{the $(2/2)$th term}+\text{the $(2/2+1)$th term})}2 = \frac{1 + 5}2 = 3$$

whence is different from the $(2/2+1)$th term, which is $5$.

Comment: For {1,5},wouldn't median be 5 taking into consideration the above quote..it cleary says that or am i missing something! thanks.

Comment: thanks for that nice explanation

Comment: You're welcome :).

Comment: When the instructions say the "closest whole number higher value" they must mean closest integer, not closest member of the set being analyzed...

Comment: @user58220 Such is in exact agreement with the answer given.

Answer (score 2):

Medians do not always have to conform to a .0 or .5 decimal ending. For example, if you assume your data to be continuous (as often is the case), then the formula for calculating a median is more sophisticated (requires more arithmetic). An example where this applies is if you're dealing with student ratings of a college class, where students only have options of rating 1 to 6, but might want to respond somewhere in-between two integers (e.g., 5.6).

This video does a decent job of explaining the arithmetic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2jskLXBhnwA